# How to make Dijit Editor keep &nbsp;?

Tags: javascript, editor, dojo, html-entities

Dijit Editor removes all `&nbsp;` entities from user input.

With a Dijit Editor in hand, go into HTML mode, enter some text with some `&nbsp;` inside. Go back to WYSIWYG mode, back to HTML mode, then see that your entity disappeared.

Is there any workaround?

HTML

```
<h1>Test file for Editor &amp;nbsp support</h1>
<div id="br" data-dojo-type="dijit.Editor" data-dojo-props='plugins:["viewsource"]'><p>a&nbsp;b</p></div>
```

Javascript

```
require(['dijit/dijit', 'dijit/Editor', 'dijit/_editor/plugins/ViewSource', 'dojo/parser'], function(dijit, editor, viewSource, parser){});
```

And the same here to play : http://jsfiddle.net/ABaYL/2/

Answer (score 1):

I think this problem is not dojo related.

The entity did not disappear. It was converted to its character. The entity "&nbsp;" was converted to its representation as a character " ". So the entites respresentation is still there. If you want to display &nbsp;, write "& amp ; nbsp;" without the spaces, but i think you already know that since you managed to display &nbsp; in your post. Even the stackoverflow editors filters &nbsp; to its representation.

Take a look here:

http://www.web2generators.com/html/entities

Comment: This is not the case with other spacing entities like &thinsp; for example. If you enter &thinsp; in HTML mode then go back/forth from HTML to WYSIWYG, you'll still have &thinsp; anyway.